# If at least two or more uppercase letters I want to change them to lowercase

Tags: notepad++

If at least two or more uppercase letters I want to change them to lowercase
with the first letter capitalized. I use Notepad++

> Example

```
FLAT TOP FADE 

Styling winglet curls can sometimes be a challenge
```

to

```
Flat top fade  

Styling winglet curls can sometimes be a challenge
```

or

```
Flat Top Fade  

Styling winglet curls can sometimes be a challenge
```

Comment: Why `TOP` doesn't become `Top`? Same question for `FADE`? They both have  more than 1 Upper. What are the rules?

Comment: if not possible it would be fine and a variation with each letter beginning with a capital letter

Comment: Both are possible. But you haven't answered my question, **What are the rules?**, why `TOP` doesn't become `Top`? And why are there  different number spaces in front of `Styling` before and after the change? If you don't answer  these questions it is impossible to answer a valid response.

Comment: Another question what should be the result for: `SnAkEs` or `sNaKeS`

Comment: Updated example:no difference or spaces. SnAkEs  to sNaKeS in my text file there are no capitalized words in the middle of the word

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<![A-Z])([A-Z])([A-Z]+.+$)`  # 1rst option
  OR
- Find what: `(?<![A-Z])([A-Z])([A-Z]+)(?![A-Z])`  # 2nd option
- Replace with: `$1\L$2`
- *check Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

*1rst option*

```
(?<![A-Z])      # negative lookbeahind, make sure we haven't upper before
([A-Z])         # group 1, 1 upper
(               # group 2
  [A-Z]+        # 1 or more upper
  .+            # 1 or more any character but newline
  $             # end of line
)               # end group 2
```

*OR 2nd option*

```
(?<![A-Z])      # negative lookbeahind, make sure we haven't upper before
([A-Z])         # group 1, 1 upper
([A-Z]+)        # group 2, 1 or more upper
(?![A-Z])       # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't upper after
```

**Replacement:** *same for both options*

```
$1          # content of group 1 (the first upper letter)
\L$2        # lowercased the content of group 2, the other letters
```

**Screen capture (1rst option):**

[image]

**Screen capture (2nd option):**

[image]

Comment: @derekas4: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)